# [PHP]Edit records,update mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table that looks like this:

```
survey_id | question_id | option_one  | option_two|  ... option_ten|
    1     |      1      |    Yes      |    No     |        ...     |
    1     |      2      |    True     |   False   |        ...     |
```

This is my code to save edited options into a 2D array before updating table:

```
   $store = array();

    $num = 0;
    foreach ($_POST['question_id'] as $option) {

        echo"<br/>";
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($option as $key) {

            $store[$num][$i] = $key;

            $i+=1;
        }

        //$question_num += 1;
        $num+=1;
    }
```

When I `print_r($store)`, it contains all the edited content,which means it works.
However when I try to Update:

```
foreach ($store as $key2 => $option2) {

        if ($option2 != NULL) {

            mysql_query(sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($option2[0]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[1]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[2]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[3]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[4]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[5]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[6]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[7]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[8]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[9]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[10]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[11]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[12]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[13])));

            $key2+=1;
        }

         $sql = "UPDATE option_table SET option_one='%s', option_two='%s', option_three='%s', option_four='%s', option_five='%s', option_six='%s', option_seven='%s',  option_eight='%s', option_nine='%s', option_ten='%s', option_eleven='%s', option_twelve='%s', option_thirteen='%s', option_fourteen='%s'
          WHERE survey_id= '$survey_id' AND question_id= '$key2'";


    }
```

It does not update properly. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I guess, `survery_id` and `question_id` are integers. Do not use quote to surround the value in query. Also, you execute query before setting the `$sql`. You should revise the code as follow:

```
if ($option2 != NULL) {
    $sql = "UPDATE option_table SET option_one='%s', option_two='%s', option_three='%s', option_four='%s', option_five='%s', option_six='%s', option_seven='%s',  option_eight='%s', option_nine='%s', option_ten='%s', option_eleven='%s', option_twelve='%s', option_thirteen='%s', option_fourteen='%s'
              WHERE survey_id= $survey_id AND question_id= $key2";
    mysql_query(sprintf($sql,mysql_real_escape_string($option2[0]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[1]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[2]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[3]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[4]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[5]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[6]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[7]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[8]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[9]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[10]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[11]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[12]), mysql_real_escape_string($option2[13])));

    $key2+=1;
}
```

*sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: I tried bt it still does nt work.When i store,instead of storing 1st qns' option to the 1st row, it stores the 2nd qns' option to the 1st.then 3rd qns' option to 2nd row.

Comment: it is because you execute query before setting the `$sql`. See updated answer